# Initial position with board "reflected"

Tags: rules, chess-variants, chessboards

The rule says that the a1 (and consequently the h8) square must be black, in other words, the leftmost square of the first row of each player must be black. With this the kings stay at the right side of the players at the initial position.

I was wondering if there are any significant changes in the game if we start it by reflecting the official initial position. With this the a1 and h8 squares would be white and the kings would stay at the left side of the players.

My thoughts are that there won't be any significant changes, because there is a bijection between all the positions with the two initial positions. In other words, for each position with respect to the official initial position there is an equivalent position with respect to the new initial position (we just have to reflect the board), and *vice versa*.

What you guys think of it?

Comment: Do you expect an explanation of the rules? Otherwise, with the bijection you mentioned, you would still play the same game, except that all of opening theory would be *reflected* as well.

Comment: Besides, an incorrect chess board layout and a wrong initial position are two different things, cf. Article 7.2 of the rules: "If during a game it is found that the chessboard has been placed contrary to Article 2.1, the game shall continue but the position reached must be transferred to a correctly placed chessboard." and "If during agame it is found that the initial position of the pieces was incorrect, the game shall be cancelled and a new game shall be played." The starting position is fixed and does not depend on the color in one corner of the chessboard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There would be no changes. It's very easy to prove.

Let's start with a board with a1 and h8 are black, and play some moves. After that, imagine that white squares turned into red ones. And keep playing. Then imagine black squares turned into white. And then finally red squares turned into black squares. Would there be any difference in the game? No.

Colors are just for our eyes, not about game mechanics.

Comment: In your transformation, the "wrong" color will have made the starting move.

Comment: @chaosflaws Consider White side as `Player 1` and Black side as `Player 2`. `Player 1` always makes the first move. Now, does it matter what color `Player 1` has?